# Changing font sizes with size classes in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, autolayout, size-classes

The new size classes for auto layout in Xcode is great, but is it also possible to change other things than constraints like font size using size classes?

Answer (score 5):

This is actually quite easy once you find the correct button. There is a small '+' sign to the left of the font select control in the inspector. Press it and choose the size class you want. Then, select different font properties for that size class.

[image: Font size]

Comment: Nice, you saved my life

Comment: Is that actually working for you?
In my case (as well as for a few other people) this only works with the System font. We managed a workaround, but so far with custom fonts it doesn't work. (Xcode 6.1 and 6.2 Beta)

Comment: @RetiefFourie I'm facing the same issue. Could you please explain the workaround you used ?

Comment: We built a Transition Manager that handles transitions for our app. So that class also provides the functionality to determine which device you use. We used that and a iVar for the font to switch out between different font sizes in viewWillAppear. It's messy and we don't like it, but there is no way that I can find to make the above method work for custom fonts. It does work fine for the system font. But I may just be doing something funny. :|